# SonarQube: Out of the box SonarQube rules differ for ResultSet and PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the following code

```
Result rs = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;

try{
   rs = <some result set>
   ps = <some preparedStatement>
   //using rs and ps before end of try block
} catch {
     //log exceptions             
} finally {
    try{
       if(rs != null) rs.close(); // (1) SonarCube detects this close() and doesn't raise any issues.
    } catch {
       //ignore
    } finally {
       rs = null;
    }

    try{
       if(ps != null) ps.close(); //(2) This close() is NOT detected by SonarCube and it complains.
    } catch {
       //ignore
    } finally {
       ps = null;
    }
}
```

So my question is what is so different about PreparedStatement as compared to ResultSet. Both are implementing AutoCloseable interface. Both are closed in the same pattern.

Please don't suggest *try-with-resources* as a solution. There are a lot of places in my code where this happens so changing all those places is not practical.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't shout.

Comment: What is the warning text from Sonar?

Comment: You might want to look up the rule that is being fired off in Sonar, I assume it would be a PMD rule but who knows. Sounds like your just fixing violations against an older code base as "Please don't suggest try-with-resources as a solution. " is a solution.

Comment: @shmosel I won't anymore. I promise.

Comment: @AlehMaksimovich It is "Use 'try-with-resource or close this 'PreparedStatement' in a 'finally' clause'".

Comment: @DarrenForsythe It's not. There are 10k such errors. I rest my case.

Comment: One difference between ResultSet and PreparedStatement is, ResultSet directly gets Autocloseable while PreparedStatement gets it from its parent aka Statement. There is a similar jira at Sonar https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1692 but is closed as 'Not Reproducible'.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to fix all pre-existing sonar issues and not setup quality to gates to trend down on them so more are not added? Its stupid to refactor _working_ code just because sonar metrics.

Comment: What is the version of SonarQube and the plugin? Knowing why the analysis is "failing" is valuable when creating new code. Maybe it is a bug.

Comment: Just as an idea: resources are acquired 1) `rs`, 2) `ps` and closed in the same order. Logic way is to close `ps` first and `rs` after. I wonder if Sonar checks the reverse order of close calls.

Comment: As mentioned : please specify the version of SonarJava used (and the version of SonarQube). If i'm correct it sounds like the first close method is considered as potentially throwing something uncaught leading to a path analyzed where the `ps.close()` is not executed.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I never said Im going to change my code to adhere to SonarQube rules. All Im expecting is that SonarQube doesnt warn me that it's a BLOCKER issue. It creates noise.

Comment: @JeroenHeier SonarQube version is Version 6.5 (build 27846).

Comment: @benzonico I dont know what SonarJava is. Could you please explain in more details?

Comment: @AlehMaksimovich good point. But not sure if thats the issue here. It's something to do with PreparedStatement. For all other resources, it works fine. And we close resources in reverse order of when they were opened.

Comment: SonarJava is the java analyzer installed on your sonarqube server and that is used to analyze the code.